# Should an AWS EC2 instance connect using only IPv4 Public IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2

If I put the "IPv4 Public IP" of my EC2 instance in the browsers address shouldnt it connect and return an error message instead of just giving time out ?

Comment: Do you have an HTTP server running on the instance? Have you allowed access via Port 80 on the Security Group associated with the instance? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: No, I do not have an HTTP server running on the instance...

Comment: I opened access to any IP on port 22. Tryed to access the instance using PuTTy. Downloaded a keyPair.perm. Usando PuttyGen converted from ´perm to .ppk. Checked for the right username ec2-user and the right address, @xxxxx. Loaded the .ppk key pair and triede to connect. Simply returns time-out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it sounds like you are attempting to connect to the instance via SSH.

Things to check:

- The **Security Group** associated with the instance needs to have port 22 open to either your Public IP address, or to `0.0.0.0/0` (which is not a good security practice)
- You are on a network that is **not blocking SSH traffic**. Some corporate network prohibit such access (so try it from home).
- The instance is running an **SSH server**. This is standard on Linux distributions, such as the Amazon Linux AMI. (Believe it or not, some people wonder why they can't SSH to a Windows instance.)
- You should be trying to connect to a **public IP address** associated with the instance
- The instance needs to be in a **Public Subnet** (which means the Route Table associated with the Subnet is pointing `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to an Internet Gateway). If you are using the Default VPC, then this is done for you.
- You have the **private half of the keypair** that was nominated when the instance was launched. If you are using an Amazon Linux instance, the private half of the keypair would have been automatically copied to: `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The fact that your connection is timing-out, as opposed to receiving an error message, most likely makes it an incorrectly configured **Security Group**. (Trust me, it's *almost always* the Security Group!)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check all thise items !

Comment: Thank you very much... Checked all that... no use. Checked also if my windows10 firewall was allowing SSH trafic, allowed PuTTy to go through the firewall, no use.

Comment: Added a rule to the security group, Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4, Echo REQUEST, now I can PING !!

Comment: The above requirements are _really_ all you need. I would suggest you launch another new Amazon Linux instance and try to SSH into it, to make sure the problem isn't on your existing instance.

Comment: John, thank you again... I have already done as you said,  have tried with 3 instances... Next time I will try another PC... Thanks again...

Comment: If new instances and a new VPC doesn't work, it is quite possibly related to the network you are on. It could be blocking outbound SSH. Or, some configuration on your own computer. Try using a different network and different computer to determine if they are the cause.

Comment: Used "InfoByIp.com" a "SSH server connectivity test", at https://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php ... Result:   -------------------------- a) Connected to ec2-18-231-166-7.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 -------------------- b) Server fingerprint is 7EACC5F5224229F9A14DB4AD49D45C05 ------  Means the server is ok, SSH ok also...   Will try another connection...

Comment: Almost 3 days lost due to a problem with the internet access provider, it seams... In Brasil we have some IAP, I do have accounts in 3 of them. I was using one by the name of "NET", works quite well. Closed this connection, connected via another one, by the name of "VIVO": connected imediately to the AWS instance... How can that be ? (will go back to the other internet access provider to double check...)  Thank you for your help, if you came across this problem again you know one more possibility...

Comment: Could be a problem with the local equipment (modem)

Comment: Changed back to the other internet connection provider, the connection was aborted with the message "PuTTY Fatal Error   Network error: Software caused connection abort"...

Comment: Lets look at it from the best side... I spent 3 days practicizing connections to AWS instances...  Well...